# DateAdd with a DateTimeoffset sometimes removes the offset

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, datetimeoffset

In an attempt to remove the time from a DateTimeOffsetValue, I can across a situation where the time zone was being removed - I'm guessing there is an implicit conversion to a DateTime happening here, but why?

```
DECLARE @d DATETIMEOFFSET = '2013-11-22 00:00:00.000 -07:00';

select
    [Original DateTimeOffset] = @d,
    [Add 1 Month] = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@d),
    [DateAdd and DateDiff] = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @d), 0);
```

The above query results in the DateAdd and DateDiff value coming out as a DateTime.  I would have thought it would be a DateTimeOffset because the input date is a DateTimeOffset.

**Original DateTimeOffset:** 2013-11-22 00:00:00.0000000 -07:00 
**Add 1 Month:** 2013-12-22 00:00:00.0000000 -07:00 
**DateAdd and DateDiff:** 2013-11-22 00:00:00.000

Why does that happen?

Comment: I am guessing when you did a datediff it removed the timezone as it returns an int and then it got converted to a datetime.

Comment: I think you're right.  So then is there a better way to get the date (without the time) but with the offset?  I ended up with an ugly calculation: TODATETIMEOFFSET(DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATE_CREATED), 0), DATEPART(tz,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))

Comment: I know this is old, but why does the offset matter if you are stripping off the time anyways? A offset is to calculate the correct time for a corresponding time zone. The offset does not effect the date unless there is a time present.

Comment: @JohnC - I'm not really stripping the time off,  I'm basically rounding down to midnight.

Comment: But if you're removing all time down to midnight, then the timezone won't matter for any of them.

Comment: I don't think that is true.  midnight in one timezone is not midnight in another timezone

Answer (score 3):

Because `int` is not castable to `datetimeoffset`. It boils down to:

```
[DateAdd and DateDiff] = 0 + 41598 days
```

How do you interpret that 0? It can't be cast directly to `datetimeoffset`:

```
SELECT CAST(0 as datetimeoffset) -- Error
SELECT CAST(CAST(0 as datetime) as datetimeoffset) -- OK
```

So SQL Server implicitly cast it to `datetime` (i.e. `1990-01-01 00:00:00`)

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up wrapping it in a TODATETIMEOFFSET function: TODATETIMEOFFSET(DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATE_CREATED), 0), DATEPART(tz,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))